# How to fix program printing a 0 after the print statement executes in C?

Tags: c, function

This program tests Goldbach's Conjecture, printing a given even integer as the sum of two primes. After printing the first one, the given integer is to iterate by 2 , then find the sum of two primes for that integer. And so on until the program is interrupted by the user.

This problem is that the program prints a '0' after every executed print statement.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int GC(int goldsum);  //function prototype 

int main()
{
    int goldsum;

    printf("Enter an even integer greater than 5: ");
    scanf("%d", &goldsum);

    printf("%d\n", GC(goldsum));

    goldsum = goldsum + 2;

    printf("%d\n", GC(goldsum));

}

int GC(int goldsum)  //function definition
{
    int i, j;       //prime addends
    int div1, div2;  //divisors
    char prime1, prime2;  

    for (i=2 ;i<goldsum ;i++) //when number is less than goldsum, run this loop iterating by 1
    {                   
        prime1 = 1;     
        for (div1=2 ;div1<i ;div1++)  //this loop determines if "i" is prime. 
            if (i % div1 == 0)  //if yes, the prime number is stored in "i"
                prime1 = 0;
        if (prime1)              
        {
            for (j=3; j<goldsum; j+=2)  //when number is less than goldsum, run this loop iterating by 2
            {
                prime1 = 1;
                for (div2=2; div2<j; div2++)   //this loop determines if "j" is prime.
                    if(j % div2 == 0)    //if yes, the prime number is stored in "j"
                        prime1 = 0;
                if (prime1)
                    if (i + j == goldsum)  //If i + j = goldsum, it prints the result. 

                    {
                        printf("%d + %d = %d\n",i ,j , goldsum);
                        return 0;
                    }

            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
Enter an even integer greater than 5: 10
3 + 7 = 10
0
5 + 7 = 12
0
```

What I want it to look like:

```
Enter an even integer greater than 5: 10
3 + 7 = 10
5 + 7 = 12
```

Comment: You print the return value of `GC` in `main`, and `GC` always returns `0`. Perhaps don't print the return value of `GC`?

Comment: Maybe you could show me what you mean? This is pretty much the second program I'm working on in C after "Hello World". I thought I was printing the print statement at the end of     GC

Comment: You don't "print a print statement"

Comment: Another answer gave a demonstration, which made it clear so I can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use just `GC(goldsum);`
instead of `printf("%d\n", GC(goldsum));`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you misunderstood the `return 0;` we put in `main()`. Every function has to return the value we desire. In the case of main we want 0 because that means everything was OK. In the case of your function the return value should be what YOU want from it.

Edit: re-read the question and adding this: Since you don't want a return value from you function you should declare it as `void` and not have it in a `printf()` because all the printing you want is in your function.

Void functions do not return a value, so that is what you want.